# Flowing errors Snap-Store 23.10

Tags: command-line, gnome, software-center, snap-store

```
$ snap-store

Gtk-Message: 08:16:56.979: Not loading module "atk-bridge": The functionality is provided by GTK natively. Please try to not load it.

** (snap-store:5155): WARNING **: 08:16:57.216: Failed to start Flutter renderer: Unable to create a GL context

** (snap-store:5155): WARNING **: 08:16:57.229: gtk.dart: failed to call method: No engine to send to

** (snap-store:5155): WARNING **: 08:16:57.229: gtk.dart: failed to call method: No engine to send to

** (snap-store:5155): WARNING **: 08:16:57.229: gtk.dart: failed to call method: No engine to send to

** (snap-store:5155): WARNING **: 08:16:57.229: gtk.dart: failed to call method: No engine to send to

** (snap-store:5155): WARNING **: 08:16:57.229: gtk.dart: failed to call method: No engine to send to

** (snap-store:5155): WARNING **: 08:16:57.229: gtk.dart: failed to call method: No engine to send to

** (snap-store:5155): WARNING **: 08:16:57.229: gtk.dart: failed to call method: No engine to send to

** (snap-store:5155): WARNING **: 08:16:57.229: gtk.dart: failed to call method: No engine to send to

** (snap-store:5155): WARNING **: 08:16:57.229: gtk.dart: failed to call method: No engine to send to

** (snap-store:5155): WARNING **: 08:16:57.229: gtk.dart: failed to call method: No engine to send to
```

I've just installed my new Ubuntu 23.10 and I am getting these errors. Please help.

Comment: I was going to ask you to add certain specific information to the question that would make it answerable, but that title distracted me. What makes this problem "Very Urgent?" Everything snap-store can do can also be done through the shell. Also, it's unclear why "gnome" and "command line" are tagged, or how they are related to the problem as shown. Another possible distraction.

Comment: Is there a problem here? These are just warnings, you can ignore them. Are they actually causing any issues?

Comment: I am experiencing this, too, on a fresh install of Ubuntu 23.10.1 on my laptop. The problem, for me, is after opening the App Store the app window is blank (there are no content or elements inside the window). The expected result is that it would have all the store elements (like "explore", "manage apps", etc.). I can provide a screenshot of the App Store if need be.